# excluir de una división de horas un rango de una hora dada

Tags: php

El titulo es un poco confuso pero a lo que quiero llegar es a lo siguiente con este codigo:

```
$hrs=['2021/08/11 08:00:00 AM','2021/08/11 08:00:00 PM'];
$fecha1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d h:i:s A', $hrs[0]);
$fecha2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d h:i:s A', $hrs[1]);
$interval = $fecha1->diff($fecha2);
$divideBy=20;

$minutes= "PT".($interval->h / $divideBy * 60)."M";
$period = new DatePeriod($fecha1, new DateInterval($minutes), $fecha2);
foreach ($period as $dt) {
    echo $dt->format("H:i:s \n");
}
```

el cual obtengo un rango de hora

- 08:00:00
- 08:36:00
- 09:12:00
- 09:48:00
- 10:24:00
- 11:00:00
- 11:36:00
- 12:12:00
- 12:48:00
- 13:24:00
- 14:00:00
- 14:36:00
- 15:12:00
- 15:48:00
- 16:24:00
- 17:00:00
- 17:36:00
- 18:12:00
- 18:48:00
- 19:24:00

De dicho rango, quiero excluir la hora de descanso por ejemplo si la hora de descanso es a las **14:00** quiero excluir de esa lista las **14:00 y 14:36**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

Puedes utilizar una condición `if` en el `foreach` y cuando se cumpla utilizar `continue` eso hará que el `foreach` salte a la siguiente iteración

Ejemplo sencillo:

```
$hrs=['2021/08/11 08:00:00 AM','2021/08/11 08:00:00 PM'];
$fecha1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d h:i:s A', $hrs[0]);
$fecha2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d h:i:s A', $hrs[1]);
$interval = $fecha1->diff($fecha2);
$divideBy=20;
$descanso = '14';

$minutes= "PT".($interval->h / $divideBy * 60)."M";
$period = new DatePeriod($fecha1, new DateInterval($minutes), $fecha2);
foreach ($period as $dt) {
    if ($dt->format("H") == $descanso) {
        continue;
    }
    echo $dt->format("H:i:s \n");
}
```

Esto devuelve:

```
08:00:00 
08:36:00 
09:12:00 
09:48:00 
10:24:00 
11:00:00 
11:36:00 
12:12:00 
12:48:00 
13:24:00 
15:12:00 
15:48:00 
16:24:00 
17:00:00 
17:36:00 
18:12:00 
18:48:00 
19:24:00
```

Si deseas puedes crear una variable `DateTime` con la hora del descanso y comparar en el `if`

Comment: Gracias fue sencillo  pero tengo un error cuando lo divido con 13, 23  me arroja lo siguiente > Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: DateInterval::__construct(): Unknown or bad format (PT31.304347826087M)

Comment: ¿Cómo que lo divides? ¿Que fue lo que pusiste?

Comment: $divideBy es manual numero enteros por ejemplo si en el form le coloco 13 el hace un submit y cambia ese valor de esa variable

Comment: Ya veo, pero ese problema no está relacionado con la pregunta original. Es mejor publicar un solo problema por pregunta para que otros usuarios encuentren la respuesta a sus preguntas. Por favor crea una nueva pregunta y con gusto te ayudo